# Nested JSON Data Parsing

Tags: python-3.x, function, api, for-loop, nested

I am trying to parse a response from an API and am running into a problem of extracting a specific value from a nested list of dictionaries within the response. Here is a snippet:

[{'fieldId': '27d8ea79-d59c-4089-8763-09af28958838', 'name': 'Source Tracking Code', 'value': 'NAD 2020', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'fieldId': '07258695-2199-41f7-97bb-d44e7f1cf6bc', 'name': 'Registration Status', 'value': 'Registered', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'fieldId': '2bd56482-9941-47e8-95e3-6acc42f42a5a', 'name': 'Seventeen or Younger', 'value': 'false', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'}, {'fieldId': '3b2c5a93-6d99-4a98-8519-f1a998b4e215', 'name': 'Status', 'value': 'false', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'}, {'fieldId': '4cfb1b32-7b64-4d15-b5d3-b767e8b42d36', 'name': 'Race or Ethnicity', 'value': 'African-American', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'fieldId': '59f5b00e-c00f-4981-b4a5-5e62615dce62', 'name': 'Photo Waiver', 'value': 'true', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'}, {'fieldId': '5b4444a0-6960-42c5-aae1-fbfd8f0e7983', 'name': 'Status', 'value': 'Active', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'fieldId': '5d276915-0f81-43e5-bc1c-03f7092e5f14', 'name': 'Party', 'value': Yes, 'type': 'STRING'}, {'fieldId': '6a6ecb71-ca6f-4637-bfc2-3fb53c1ab14e', 'name': 'New Status', 'value': 'false', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'}, {'fieldId': '6dbd00e1-6c38-436e-b04b-ad8583004d59', 'name': 'Age', 'value': '35', 'type': 'NUMBER'}, {'fieldId': '879364da-64fa-42af-a720-ea299a67fdb2', 'name': 'Assistance', 'value': 'true', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'}, {'fieldId': '880d4356-bfaa-46d1-9b5d-007e17c13180', 'name': 'No Text', 'value': 'false', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'}, {'fieldId': '8ba4046f-b0e5-4a6d-993f-176292d1d3fb', 'name': 'Liability Waiver', 'value': 'true', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'}, {'fieldId': '9249f64a-c37b-4498-aabb-484ceb4abb18', 'name': 'Interest', 'value': 'false', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'}, {'fieldId': 'a5110cc7-4578-4cf9-bba7-404a5b4fe779', 'name': 'Score', 'value': '33.1', 'type': 'BIGDECIMAL'}, {'fieldId': 'bf9da203-5b7f-48b0-8889-9eba340cd263', 'name': 'Delete CRM Record', 'value': 'false', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'}, {'fieldId': 'c13eea40-7de3-42a7-b5ed-bea718b48ce5', 'name': 'Will you pay the additional cost for a single room?', 'value': 'false', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'}, {'fieldId': 'c53fdc12-4b7c-4f35-aed7-0d9856e42cac', 'name': 'Name', 'value': 'DISTRICT, 'type': 'STRING'}, {'fieldId': 'c62b7652-1517-4f4e-a986-b3d08fd4fede', 'name': 'Score', 'value': '97.4', 'type': 'BIGDECIMAL'}, {'fieldId': 'd0958dd7-c16a-4d69-b3f2-a14d83c0dd3e', 'name': 'ID', 'value': 'L250', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'fieldId': 'd5d82695-0f24-483c-9304-2ab4bedc6294', 'name': 'days you will attend:', 'value': 'Monday, 9 a.m. - 8 p.m.', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'fieldId': 'ea8e091f-27df-41d8-b866-6f14cad4e457', 'name': 'Do Not Call', 'value': 'false', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'}, {'fieldId': 'f7b21731-f931-40ec-964f-db18b0d2d0d3', 'name': 'Marital Status', 'value': 'Unmarried', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'fieldId': 'fbb40bca-5929-4712-8595-51ab832ad8f7', 'name': 'How are you be attending?', 'value': 'In person', 'type': 'STRING'}]

This snippet is for one record. So there is a name field, address field and so in. The above snippet comes from a field called customFieldValues in the API response.

What I am looking to do is extract just the age value. Since it is tagged unhelpfully as 'value' as the key within the dictionary. There aren't any indexes here to work with either since this is metadata in a singular field.

I am ultimately trying to group this with other fields in the API response and here is my code this far after getting the response back:

```
json_package = []
for row in json_keys:
    SID = row['Id']
    State = row['address']

    **age = row['customFieldValues']**

    a_key = 'value'
    Handle = row['contacts']
    list_values = [a_list[a_key] for a_list in Handle]
    string = str(list_values).split(",")

    data = {
        'SID': SID,
        'State': State['state'],
        **'Age' : age,**
        'Email': strip_characters(string[-1]),

    }
    json_package.append(data)
```

where strip characters is a function I build to clean up some of the braces, brackets and empty spaces in the field.

I have tried for loops, creating functions to isolate but can't quite get to the value in accordance with the member record in the API.

Everything else is working just fine but I can't this one last piece so any help is appreciated.

Any suggestions?